# Change Pydantic's inherited BaseModel's attribute precedence in JSON schema

Tags: json, python-3.x, fastapi, pydantic

I'm using `pydantic 1.6.1` and `fastapi 0.61.1` with Python 3.8.3. Here's how I've tried defining the models:

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    name: str

class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str

class UserInfo(UserBase):
    id: str
    group: Optional[GroupInfo] = None
```

The issue I'm having with this setup is that the schema is built such that the `name` attribute is on top of the remaining attributes like so - in this case, while using `UserInfo` as the endpoint's `response_model`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "string",
    "id": "string",
    "group": {
      "name": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

Yet I'd like to be able to set them up like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "group": {
      "name": "string"
    }
  }
]
```

Is there a way I can manually set a custom order for the attributes in the JSON response's schema?

Comment: Does the order really matter?  *"An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs."*  (Source [json.org](http://json.org/))

Comment: @ArakkalAbu In the grand scheme of things, not really. Still, I'd rather have this option available for presentation purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, it doesn't really matter the order of the JSON, but when it comes to schema generation, it can be helpful.

You need to *decouple* the **`id`** field from **`UserInfo`** model as

```
class UserID(BaseModel):
    id: str


class UserInfo(UserBase, UserID): # `UserID` should be second
    group: Optional[GroupInfo] = None
```

This will generate the following JSON schema,

```
{
  "id": "string",
  "name": "string",
  "group": {
    "name": "string"
  }
}
```

#### Bit more ugly solution (IMO)

patch the **`.__fields__`** as

```
class UserBase(BaseModel):
    name: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    password: str


class UserInfo(UserBase):
    id: str
    group: Optional[GroupInfo] = None


fields = UserInfo.__fields__.copy()
UserInfo.__fields__ = {"id": fields.pop("id"), **fields}
```